# Display two separated records according to multiple values in properties neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I faced a need to make a strange thing. I have some query which is can’t be changed. It’s a match query for getting record:

```
MATCH (j:journal) WHERE j.id in [12] RETURN j.`id` AS ID, j.`language` AS LANGUAGE
```

And I have some node that contains array as property: e.g. can be created like this: `create (j:journal {id:12, language:[“English”, “Polish”]})`

So, is there any possibility to display this node like two records with the same id, but with different language fields? Like the following:

ID | LANGUAGE

12 | English

12 | Polish

The important thing is that match query can’t be changed at all.
But the node can be changed.

I know that I can add UNWIND keyword for the language field in the source query. But there is a requirement to not to.

I didn’t find something like that in the documentation nor in the internet. I’m not sure if it’s even possible (but consumer wants it). Just I don’t have much experience with neo4j.

I understand that it can sound weird, but I need to understand if it can be implemented this way.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can change the DB, you can change it so that each `journal` node contains a single language (as a scalar value, not in a list). However, this change might break any other queries that you might have.

If this conversion is acceptable, here is a query that should: (a) convert existing `journal` nodes to have a scalar `language` value, and (b) create new `journal` nodes as necessary for the remaining language values. The nodes that are spawned from an original `journal` node will share the same properties (except for `language`).

```
MATCH (j:journal)
WITH j, j.language[1..] AS langs
SET j.language = j.language[0]
WITH j, langs
UNWIND langs AS lang
CREATE (k:journal)
SET k = j, k.language = lang
```

If a node's `language` property had N values, you will end up with N nodes, each with the same properties -- **except** for the `language` property, which will contain a different language value (as a string). For efficiency, the original node is reused.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But it seems like it will be a copy of nodes, isn’t?

Comment: I've added an explanation to the bottom of my answer.

Comment: Thank you kindly! That looks exactly like a solution. I just need to check compatibility with other queries. Thank you again